# Проблема с размером Thumb при изменении размера Adorner UIElement

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток !

Читаю `svg`, в роли холста `ZoomableCanvas` создаю элементы `Shape (Path, ellipse, rectangle и т.д.).` Всё нормально, в общем получаю изображение один к одному. Далее мне требуются изменения геометрии некоторых из точек данного рисунка, для этого я создал для каждого из `Shape` объектов свой `Adorner`. Упёрлось всё в такой момент при увеличении изображения:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseWheelCanvas(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var x = Math.Pow(2, e.Delta / 10.0 / Mouse.MouseWheelDeltaForOneLine);
    if (e.Delta > 0)
    {
        if ((sender as ZoomableCanvas).Scale <= 34.29)
        {
            (sender as ZoomableCanvas).Scale *= x;
            SetScaleToLabel((float)(sender as ZoomableCanvas).Scale * 100);
            var position = (Vector)e.GetPosition(theGrid);
            (sender as ZoomableCanvas).Offset = (Point)((Vector)((sender as ZoomableCanvas).Offset + position) * x - position);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        (sender as ZoomableCanvas).Scale *= x;
        SetScaleToLabel((float)(sender as ZoomableCanvas).Scale * 100);
        var position = (Vector)e.GetPosition(theGrid);
        (sender as ZoomableCanvas).Offset = (Point)((Vector)((sender as ZoomableCanvas).Offset + position) * x - position);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

или его уменьшении. Вместе с этим увеличиваются все `Thumb`, находящиеся на `Adorner` слое. Как сделать, чтобы все `Thumb`, которые находятся на точках при зуминге, не изменяли свой размер? На данный момент получается так:

```
public override GeneralTransform GetDesiredTransform(GeneralTransform transform)
{
    return base.GetDesiredTransform(transform);
}
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
    var result = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    InvalidateVisual();
    return result;
}
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    return finalSize;
}
```